# How can I loop through this nested array and create a model from each item? [Java]

Tags: java, loops, class, recursion, nested

Say each Person here has 3 key value pairs, name, age, and children. I want to iterate through the potentially endlessly nested list and create a new "Parent" model from each person. From each person model I need to create a List of Person models for each level of nesting, and if a particular person has a children, the children property on that Person model will contain a subsequent List of the correct children. (Note the main resulting nesting list of Persons is stored elsewhere in memory, I just need help creating them like in my example)

```
Example Structure:

Persons
- Person
- Person
    - Person
- Person
    - Person
        - Person
        - Person

Each Person above has a name, age, and children property.

ex. 
{Persons: 
    [name: John, age: 18, children: null},
     {name: Lisa, age: 32, children: [{ name: Tyler, age: 7, children: null}],
     {name: Mike, age: 90, children: [{name: Derek, age 50, children: 
                                                 [{name: Mary, age:25, children: null},
                                                 {name: Beth, age:16, children: null}]}]};
```

Recursion is not my strongest area and i'm struggling greatly with how to loop through a potentially very deep nested object. I know this is very wrong as i'm only covering the first layer of nesting. I think I should use a createPerson method like I wrote at the bottom, and use a recursive function to but I'm struggling a lot. Any insight is hugely appreciated!

ListPerson API returns Persons[] persons

```
private void loadPersons(String id) {

    ListPersonsApi.Request request = Jso.create();
    request.id = id;

    dispatcher.send(ListPersonsApi.PATH, request, r-> {

        for (ListPersonsApi.persons p : r.persons) {

            List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
            PersonModel person = new Person();
            person.name = p.name;
            person.age = p.age;
            persons.add(person);
            parent.children = persons;
            
            // Everything below this is wrong of course but its the logic I was thinking of using
            List<Person> children = p.children;
            while(children != null) {
               for (ListPersonsApi.persons q : p.children) {
                   createPerson(p, q)
                   children = children.children;
        }
    })
}

       
private void createPerson(PersonModel parent, p) {

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        PersonModel person = new Person();
        person.name = p.name;
        person.age = p.age;
        persons.add(person);
        parent.children = persons;
}
```

Comment: To clarify your question, you'd like to traverse the structure and return a list of all the `Person` objects, and those objects should have the properly nested `Person` list, in the event they have children?

Comment: Please edit the question. It will help if you show *both* example input and desired result. I suggest adding one to three additional people in the example.  In addition, please consider presenting the code as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which should include the relevant parts of `class Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm; I haven't adapted your code since I don't have access to many of the objects.

You're right, a recursive call is what you need to accomplish this, although I'm sure there are other measures available.

Let's consider the following, a class to hold the information, call it `Person`.
I've additionally provided an overridden `toString` method, so we can print the information out.

```java
static class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Person> children;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    Person(String name, int age, List<Person> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String string = "'%s', %d, ".formatted(name, age);
        if (children == null)
            return string + "no children";
        else {
            if (children.size() == 1) return string + "1 child";
            else return string + children.size() + " children";
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I've created a class, call it `Example`, which contains a single field, and a method.
The field is a `List` of `Person`, which we'll use to hold the data generated by the recursive method.
The method is a recursive function, which will traverse the given list, and add the person to the list.
Subsequently, if the person has children, they will be added to the list as well, by making a recursive call, and providing the list.

```java
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

void persons(List<Person> list) {
    for (Person person : list) {
        persons.add(person);
        if (person.children != null) {
            persons(person.children);
        }
    }
}
```

In a separate method, I populated a list, for demonstration purposes.
It is equivalent to the example data you supplied, with the same names, ages, and children.

If I run the class and print `persons`, I get the following data.

```
'John', 18, no children
'Lisa', 32, 1 child
'Tyler', 7, no children
'Mike', 90, 1 child
'Derek', 50, 2 children
'Mary', 25, no children
'Beth', 16, no children
```

So, if I'm correct, given these procedures, you could change your `loadPersons` method to the following.

```java
private void loadPersons(String id) {
    ListPersonsApi.Request request = Jso.create();
    request.id = id;
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    dispatcher.send(ListPersonsApi.PATH, request, r -> {
        for (ListPersonsApi.persons p : r.persons)
            list.add(new Person(p.name, p.age, p.children));
    });
    persons(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each person you have the "children" information given. That implicitly makes that person the children's parent. And looking at your data it is very much recursive, but if you prefer it could be solved with iterations as well. Depends on how you host the objects in memory.

So loop over all persons (with/without recursion). With that person (named P) iterate over all the children (named C). Set the child's parent relationship to P.

In some improved version of your program you could, before setting the child's parent check if no parent was registered before, or if a parent was set it should be no different to the parent you would set it to. That way you could validate some of the input data.